# Parsing XML using NSXML for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsxmlparser

I have an XML which has a structure like this:

```
<data>
   <books>
      <item>
          <title>book1</title>
          <author>author1</author>
      </item> 
      <item>
          <title>book2</title>
          <author>author2</author>
      </item>
   </books>
   <magazines>
      <item>
          <title>Mag1</title>
          <author>author1</author>
      </item>
   </magazines>
   <journals>
      <item>
          <title>Journal1</title>
          <author>author1</author>
      </item> 
      <item>
          <title>Journal2</title>
          <author>author2</author>
      </item>
   </journals>
</data>
```

I am using a table view to display the items of each category. I plan to have a table view with columns books, magazines & journals and clicking on them should display only the items under them. That is, if I click on books, it should only display the book entries.

I have this for xml parsing

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"books"]) {
        flag=1;
    }   

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"]) {   
        NSLog(@"found title!");
        parsedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"author"]) {  
        NSLog(@"description found");
        parsedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}
```

and in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (flag==1){   
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"]) {
        [headlines addObject:parseString];

        [parseString release];
        parseString = nil;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"author"]) {
        [authors addObject:parsedString];
        [parseString release];
        parseString = nil;
        flag=2;
        }
    }
}
```

But this gets only the first entry of books and nothing else. 
Instead of setting flags is there a way to parse only between the <books> and 
</books> tags ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is only getting the first item is that you are setting flag to 2 when you see the end element for the author tag. I suspect you will get closer to what you want if you update this flag in the end element for the books tag, as follows:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  if (flag==1){   
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"]) {
        [headlines addObject:parseString];

        [parseString release];
        parseString = nil;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"author"]) {
        [authors addObject:parsedString];
        [parseString release];
        parseString = nil;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"books"]) {
        flag=2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel parsing when the books tag ends:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{  
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"books"]) {
        [parser abortParsing];
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: This approach will only work if you are trying to get the books section, which happens to be first in the XML, as in the example. But if you want to apply the same logic for retrieving "magazines" and "journals" sections, it won't help much.

Comment: I tried this now. The cells in my tableview upon clicking goes a screen which displays the author name. It works fine, but when I come back to the table view and click on the item again, it crashes.

Basically, what I am trying to do is parse only the tags within books, parse only the tags within Magazines etc. So, in case I am parsing magazines, it should not parse the tags under books & journals.

Comment: @RBK - this is another problem probably not connected with parsing.

Comment: @Max I think something else is wrong as you said. But as Tim said, it works only for books & not for the rest.